# Литература по теме "Как написать оптимизированный код на scala"

Tags: оптимизация, scala

Хотел бы почитать какую-нибудь литературу по теме: "Как написать оптимизированный код на scala", ну или хотя бы что нужно знать, понимать, чтобы писать код оптимизированным. Под оптимизированным кодом имеется ввиду скорость выполнения программы.

Comment: [Вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/333362/) неплохая шпаргалка по теме. Не руководство по оптимизации, конечно, но явных подводных камней позволит избежать.

Comment: в плане скорости Scala -- не лучший выбор. Скорее всего придется писать максимально близко к Java, но в этом случае теряются большинство плюшек языка. Scala позволяет легко паралелить, но паралельное еще не значит "более быстрое".
Обычно хватает оптимизации узких мест, поэтому основная задача -- найти такие места.

Comment: в ссылке @extm скорее описание того, как не писать излишне медленный код.